# How to use one column in two different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two different tables named `product` and `purchase`.

The `product` table consists of product id, product desc, product cost. Now I want to use the same product id in the purchase table which is present in the product table, so that when I enter the product id I can get all the information regarding the product id from both the tables.

Comment: SQL 101 - use a **foreign key** `product id`  in `Purchase` that references `Product.ProductId` and use JOINs to combine the values from both tables

Comment: See: [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to query this data.

Comment: hi sunilkar9, welcome to stackoverflow. by the sound of it, perhaps you need a [foreign key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one column in two or more different tables just by using **foreign_key** constraint.
after this.
use SQL Joins.